# Beating CSRF using TOKENS

Tags: security

I am new to web programming.
I read an article where they advised to use tokens as a hidden field in forms and match that token at the server end to detect non-legitimate requests.
I am wondering what difference does it make, if an attacker uses an iframe to fetch a form,that form is going to have the token id generated at server and it should be matched.I went through article on owasp.org but it sounds too cryptic for me.

Comment: This question probably belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/, unless it's too simple of a question for that site.

Comment: Cross post of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60892/beating-csrf-using-tokens

Comment: Please do not cross post - flag your question as `other` and ask a moderator to migrate it for you. ;-)